# What's the difference between 'have an influence on something' and 'influence something'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

How is 'have an influence on something' different from influence something?

Comment: Both essentially mean the same - verb form of influence - i.e. "rules can influence actions" and "rules have an influence on actions". Can you specify the context or the sentences you're dealing with?

Comment: The only difference I can see is that one might have more of a passive use, with the other being more active.

Comment: There is no difference at all. This is simply a different, and somewhat longer, way to express the action. Similarly, _give a shove/push_ means _shove_ or _push_, _have a smoke/drink_ means _smoke_ or _drink_, and _take a stand/position_ means _stand_ or _position_. Verbs like _take, give, go, have_ are called "small verbs" in the trade, and they participate in thousands of idioms like these.

Comment: *Influenced* is generally interpreted as stronger than *had an influence*.

Comment: Thank you very much!I have been wondering Which is natural for a long Time.